# Makefile: target pattern contains no `%'

Tags: makefile

Why does my Makefile not work?

makefile:

```
app-reset:
     bin/console avanzu:admin:fetch-vendor
```

`make app-reset` is returning:

```
makefile:3: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Does your `bin/console ...` line start with an actual tab character?

Comment: Well ... no. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As explained in https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recipe-Syntax, every line in your build recipe must start with a tab character. If you use anything else (such as a sequence of spaces), you get confusing errors.

Usually this manifests as `Makefile:42: *** missing separator. Stop.` but in your case the colons (`:`) in your command confused make into thinking you were trying to define a pattern rule.

In any case, the solution is to use a tab character instead. (Or, if you are using GNU make, set [`.RECIPEPREFIX`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002eRECIPEPREFIX-_0028change-the-recipe-prefix-character_0029).)

Answer (score -4):

Can you try this?

```
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32z1
```

I meet same problem in 18.04, but I pass the make after install `lib32ncurses5 lib32z1`.