# how do i fix; makefile:1: *** target pattern contains no '%'. Stop

Tags: makefile

I'm new to Linux, so for my undergraduate project, I am working on Ubuntu and I have been trying to configure Freeswitch...almost having a breakthrough. Then finally, to use `make && make install`, it brought:

```
"makefile:1: *** target pattern contains no '%'. Stop."
```

Please, what should I do

Comment: This should be moved to a more appropriate SE site, and cleaned up a bit to make it clearer what you are asking. Maybe https://askubuntu.com/ or https://serverfault.com/?

Comment: This question is perfectly fine here.  There's nothing Ubuntu specific about it, nor is it related to system admin.

Comment: "Please, what should I do?" You should provide exact steps by which some reader can reproduce your problem.

Comment: As I said earlier, I am new to all this. How do I read the makefile.

Comment: Might be an issue with using spaces vs. tabs
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46008857/2376049

Answer (score 5):

Well, it would help greatly if you provided the content of your `makefile` at line 1 (where the error is reported to be, by `makefile:1:`).  Without that we can only guess.

But basically what that message means is that you have used [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html) syntax, but your target pattern(s) don't contain any pattern token (`%`).  What this usually means is you have a "stray" colon in your rule that you didn't expect or want.  Without seeing your makefile rules we can't say more than that.

Also very useful is the GNU make manual section [Errors Generated by Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html) which should give you a description of the error.